# Execute script only if update command did something

Tags: vim

I am new to vimscript so this is probably and easy one. I know of the `update` command which is like `write` except it only writes if there have been changes made. I would like to have something like

```
if ( update )
    call expensiveOperation()
```

where the expensive operation is only called if `update` actually did something. But, I'm not familiar enough with vim to know how to do this. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, it is possible: `update` does some operation if `&modified` option appears to be true (this option’s value is ignored when `&buftype` is either “nofile” or “nowrite”). Hence you should do the following:

```
let wasmodified=(&modified && !(&buftype is# 'nowrite' || &buftype is# 'nofile'))
update
if wasmodified
    call ExpensiveOperation()
endif
```